# Trying to find the path for subversion

Tags: nas, svn-server

I've installed [a module](http://www.thecus.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=36&t=3074) for a thecus N5500 NAS that allows me to run svn and websvn directly on the nas.

The path to the repository on the NAS is `/raid/data/svnrepo` and I've copied the files from my old repository (Mac 10.6.8 Apache svn) to that location. When I launch websvn at `https://nas.ip/modules/Subversion/www/listing.php?repname=Standardrepository` everything appears to be working.

However, I cannot seem to work out what the URL to connect from my client should be.
I've tried `http://nas.ip/svn` and `svn+ssh://sshuser@nas.ip/raid/data/svnrepo` and various other combinations.

Frustratingly, there's been no response to a post to the module's author about this, so I can only assume the answer must be obvious.

Can anyone provide some insight?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server is started with `-r /raid/data/svnrepo`, so all URLs will be interpreted as being relative to that directory.

Just `svn://nas.ip/` should give you access. Default user/password is `svn`/`svn` unless you have a custom `passwd` file.